How would I replicate this background glow accent in React native?
I am trying to replicate the purple glow coming from the corner of the background in the example shown below.

I tried replicating the effect with react-native-svg.
import { Defs, RadialGradient, Rect, Stop, Svg } from "react-native-svg";

export default function ScreenWrapper({ children }: { children: any }) {
  return (
    <Svg height="150" width="300">
      <Defs>
        <RadialGradient
          id="grad-8"
          cx="10%" //Set the radius corner by x
          cy="10%" //Set the radius corner by y
          r="70%" //Set the gradient radius
        >
          <Stop
            offset="0"
            stopColor="#fff" //Set the Gradient color(From)
            stopOpacity="0"
          />
          <Stop
            offset="1"
            stopColor="#220a3f" //Set the Gradient color(To)
          />
        </RadialGradient>
      </Defs>
      <Rect x="10" y="10" width="290" height="130" fill="url(#grad-8)" />
    </Svg>
  );
}

I managed to get this, but I'm not sure how to make it similar to the effect shown in the example. Are there any other ways I could try besides using Svgs?


This question is similar to: Does React Native styles support gradients?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
